# How to show the select editor text but not value in Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

As the [editor select](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/edit#edit)

```
values: {
    "steve": "Steve Boberson",
    "bob": "Bob Jimmerson",
    "jim": "Jim Stevenson",
}
```

I can find that this object key will be the value of cell data([see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4x1O.png)), but can 
it be similar with html select, I mean the select option text is for user, and the value is for the developer.

```
<select>
    <option value="steve">Steve Boberson</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Hope this post helps you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57464360/tabulator-how-to-create-a-dynamic-custom-editor-based-on-another-cells-value/66881116#66881116

Answer (score 1):

You should use the built in ***lookup*** formatter to do this:

```
{title:"Example", field:"example", formatter:"lookup", formatterParams:{
    "small": "Cute",
    "medium": "Fine",
    "big": "Scary",
}}
```

you can pass the same object into the ***formatterParams*** as you do into the ***values*** property of the ***editorParams***

Comment: Hi, Oli! When I edit cell with value which has `editor: "autocomplete"` cell show value instead title. [example](https://jsfiddle.net/alopatin/csq6om8e/12/) How can I resolve with a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It works if using customize formatter to reformat the content which for user to see as the following link.

```
Visit https://jsfiddle.net/allensimth/zb6engfr
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this for my needs with a custom formatter. "metricList" is a variable that contains label and value populated by a DB.   So the values are in "metricList".

The custom format then checks to see if there is a value in the cell, and if yes, find the Label for the value and return that.

```
{title:"Metric", field:"metricid", editor:"select", download:false,
            editorParams: {
                values: metricList
            },
            formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
                if (cell.getValue() > 0) {
                    return metricList.find(obj => obj.value == cell.getValue()).label
                } else {
                    return ""
                }

            }
    },
```