# I use the Tabulator List editor to have a list of teachers. I need to use the teacher id but I need to show the label in the cell

Tags: javascript, select, tabulator

I fill a select using the list editor. It works fine and the values are displayed.
I need to use the selected id to make an ajax query to the database. To do this I need to get the id of the teacher by selecting an element of the select. When I select it, I get its value, but that value is displayed in the cell. And the ideal is that the label is shown in the cell and at the same time I can save the value of the id in a variable and then send it by ajax using the cellEdited.

```
var tableData = [
    {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", profesor:"John Smith"},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female",profesor:"Laura Ingalls"},
]

var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tableData, //set initial table data
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Age", field:"age"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
      
        {title:"Profesor", width:200,field:"profesor", editor:"list", editorParams:{
         valuesLookup:function(cell, filterTerm){
        //cell - the cell component for the current cell
        //filterTerm - the current value of the input element

        return [
            {"value":"3","label":"Castillo, Juan"},{"value":"4","label":"Baracus, Mario"}
        ];
    },
        
        itemFormatter:function(label, value, item, element){
          return "<strong>" + label + " </strong><br/><div>" + item.value + "</div>";
        }
        
        
        }
      },
    ],
});

table.on("cellEdited", function(cell){
  //cell - cell component
  var id = cell.getRow().getData().id;
  var col = cell.getColumn().getField();
  var cellValue = cell.getValue();

  console.log("I need to use the value:" + cellValue + " But the cell must show the label");
 
});



[Example in CodePen]: https://codepen.io/pepocero/pen/dygEWYM
```

I don't know if it can be done.
Sorry for my bad English

[Codepen Example](https://codepen.io/pepocero/pen/dygEWYM)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53367573/how-to-show-the-select-editor-text-but-not-value-in-tabulator?rq=2):

```
{title:"Metric", field:"metricid", editor:"select", download:false,
            editorParams: {
                values: metricList
            },
            formatter:function(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
                if (cell.getValue() > 0) {
                    return metricList.find(obj => obj.value == cell.getValue()).label
                } else {
                    return ""
                }

            }
    },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you share your metricList here, please? Thanks!